# Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Height' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf

An in-house application coded in C# and WPF works without incident for 20+ people except one user. The first window displayed usually (but not always) results in an exception that our exception handler diligently reports:

```
Exception trace:
Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Height' threw an exception.
Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.

Stack trace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

There's no obvious problem with the XAML, and I'm never directly touching the height of any element. I've tried making the window default to a larger or smaller size, but that hasn't resolved anything. It's actually a simple user log in window. The problem often but not always goes away after goes away on reboot.

I don't expect a silver bullet to this problem, but it's not clear where I should begin in debugging -- WPF seems to have a design flaw that makes it nearly impossible to debug such exceptions?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer as it probably won't be of any final help. But if you Google `XAML Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation`, you'll find plenty of other forumtopics, blogposts, etc... about this. I guess a lot of people run in to this, I haven't though.

Comment: Aye, I've found a many similar sounding errors, but every time it ends up being something unrelated (e.g. I don't even have what they find is the problem) or unresolved. It almost feels like an memory initialization problem -- but due to how C# default values work, that's not going to be in my code.

Comment: Although I haven't heard of the floating point calculation methods being altered and left in an unexpected state.. I'll try seeing if working around that works.

Comment: So, curiously that *seems* to have fixed the problem. I added a call to reset floating point calculation type at application startup. See the bottom post of http://goo.gl/L1L4Fa for details. Due to the somewhat sporadic nature of the repro I can't be sure, however. If the problem doesn't come back in a few days I'll update this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching again as Abbas suggested, this is the solution I ended up with:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    [DllImport("msvcr71.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int _controlfp(int n, int mask);

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        _controlfp(0x9001F, 0xFFFFF);

        // ... whatever else you want to do on application startup
        // e.g. add last-resort error handler via DispatcherUnhandledException
    }
}
```

Some software apparently can leave floating point calculation modes in an unexpected state. The `_controlfp` call sets it back to the expected mode.